# Selenium Python Webdriver hangs after timeout from renderer, even when error is caught

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I set a page load timeout of 40 seconds.
I catch these timeout errors with a simple try, except statement.
Event when these errors are caught, ChromeDriver hangs and can no longer navigate, even when manually entering a URL into the browser.

How can I get around this problem?

The error message is the classic:

```
Timed out receiving message from renderer:40.00
```

As mentioned, catching this error does not work, because once it occurs, Webdriver no longer functions on my system. I am using Linux and the relevant parts of my code are here:

```
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=sel_options, options=options, use_subprocess=True)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": agent})
    
driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)

def navigate(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except:
        print("navigation error")
```